# Horizontally center two UILabels in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, autolayout, centering

I have two `UILabel`s in a `UITableViewCell`. Both have same width and height.

[image]

Consider these two labels as a group. I need to center this label group inside the cell horizontally. Important thing to note is that these cells are self-sizing. Meaning the cell's height depend on the content inside it so the height will vary. I need the label group to be centered no matter what the height is. The labels must keep that vertical space between them.

Currently I have set the following constraints to the two labels.

Top label - Leading Space to Superview, Top Space to Superview
Bottom label - Leading Space to Superview, Bottom Space to Superview 
Both labels - Vertical Space

And the result is this.

[image]

The first cell, its displaying as I want to. But as you can see, when the height changes, the labels go crazy as expected since the Top Space and Bottom Space constraints are getting different values. I need those two labels to look like in the first cell in all cells.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this? Is it possible to do this in IB or do I have to dig into setting Auto Layout constraints in code?

Thank you.

Comment: if you want to stack the 3 labels together in fix distance, why not crating a container view with clear background and set the "center" constraints to this view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set for each label constraint Editor->Align->Vertical center in container

Comment: Got it! Thank you. I didn't know you could set a value to that constraint.

Comment: Hello @Isuru, how did you solve this issue? I have also same issue

Comment: @Isuru, have to set only that, or other constraints too.

Comment: @Ranjit It depends on your layout. To position a control from a certain value from the horizontal center, you need to set the above constraint.

Comment: @Isuru, please look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103760/applying-autolayout-constraints-to-multiple-objects Here I want to place a UIlabel which will be placed on the right corner and it should be always at the center based on the cells height.

Answer (score 0):

Add "horizontal center in container" constraint. You will find it in the left tab "Align".
Add this constraint to each label and specify the y position.

Comment: How to specify the y position? Do you mean move the y position programmelly?