# Applying autoLayout constraints to multiple objects

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am playing with autoLayout constraints in iOS

My use case is this way,

I will better explain with images

[image]

I am using a custom cell for UITableViewCell, through autolayout I have set constraints for text and divider line below and they obey autolayout constraints. **Now you can see the yellow vertical strip on the left.**

**I have not set any constraints for it, so when the cell height is normal, it covers the whole cell, but when cell height increases, it doesnt increase and fill the whole cell. I am not able to make its height flexible w.r.t to cell.**

I want to expand the yellow strip to cover the whole cell.

So how I can achieve this.

Comment: Add top, bottom, trailing and width constraints to the yellow view. That will make sure it'll stick to the right side in both orientation in the same width and height. For the label, you shouldn't center it with the yellow view because for example in the third cell in your image above, if you center the label with the yellow view, it would overlap the other label at the bottom. Just place it above the bottom label.

Answer (score 1):

You can make height of yellow strip flexible by setting 2 constraints.

Set both top space and bottom space to container (cell's content view) to 0. 
Ensure there is no constant height constraint for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set constraints to the yellow view. By default it would apply its own constraints at runtime.

To the yellow view add TOP , BOTTOM , LEADING , and TRAILING  constraint. DO NOT ADD A HEIGHT constraint.

Make sure the TOP and BOTTOM constraints of the yellow view are pinned to the cell's content view.

Let me know if it works.

Cheers

Comment: You should not have a leading constraint if you also have a width constraint. Those two could only work for one screen size. It seems from the OP's question, that the width constraint should be the one you want.

Comment: @rdelmar Your right , but I was assuming the width of the tableView to remain constant.

Comment: Hello Navin how to center align a Uilabel on that yellow strip

Comment: So that UIlable will be at the center of yellow strip always, even if the strip increase or decrease in height

Comment: Since UILabel somehow always centres the text to its bounds you can make the UILabel match the height of the view.

Comment: what do you mean by that naveen?